Separate overlapping features
I have an issue with a specific QGIS Layer. The layer represents blocks in a city. It's made of polygons, each one representing a street, a square, a building a park and so on. When selecting the polygons with the "select features" tool, everything is fine, but if I want to inspect the features with "identify features" each click corresponds to a bundle of overlapping areas that are selected all at once. I can inspect them separately by right clicking and choosing a specific area from the bundle.
It seems that the geometry I can see does not correspond to the information contained in the attribute table. Since I pretty much just need the geometry and one single attribute from the attribute table, I would like to "explode" the layer into single not overlapping areas.
I add a picture of a multiple selected area while inspecting I got by clicking just once in the middle


You might get more help if you share a small sample of your data on something like https://wetransfer.com/

Do they have some attribute to explode by?

There are some attributes that are unique to the areas, e.g. an ID number. How would it work? Since the polygons are overlapping, even if I split them they still overlap right?
